# Limiting My Result From Past Year To Past 30 Days WITH Zeros

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that gets total results from ToxicologyTests based on the past 12 months even if there were zero that month.

```
SELECT y, m, Count(ToxicologyTests.receiveDate) as count
FROM (
  SELECT y, m
  FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y 
    UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
    (
      SELECT 1 m 
      UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
    ) months
  ) ym
  LEFT JOIN ToxicologyTests
  ON ym.y = YEAR(ToxicologyTests.receiveDate)
  AND ym.m = MONTH(ToxicologyTests.receiveDate)
  WHERE (
        y=YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND m<=MONTH(CURDATE())
  )
  OR (
        y<YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND m>MONTH(CURDATE())
  )
GROUP BY y, m
```

This will correctly output the number of tests per month even if there is zero. I have been stuck so much on trying to change this from the past 12 months to the past 30 days all while keep the zeros too if the there were no tests that day. Any suggestions?

`MYSQL`

Comment: If it was me, I'd handle the zeros in application code

Comment: while formatting the sql query to make it more readable i noticed that the closing `)` of the first `FROM` is missing, please check the query is correct

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this query? I've changed the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT y, m, Count(ToxicologyTests.receiveDate) as count
FROM (
  SELECT y, m
  FROM
   (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) y UNION ALL SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-1) years,
   (SELECT 1 m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
     UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
     UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) months) ym
  LEFT JOIN ToxicologyTests
  ON ym.y = YEAR(ToxicologyTests.receiveDate)
  AND ym.m = MONTH(ToxicologyTests.receiveDate)
WHERE ToxicologyTests.receiveDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY y, m
```